# Does the problem of recognizing 3DORG-graphs have polynomial complexity?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

A 2DORG is the intersection graph of a finite family of rays directed $\to$ or $\uparrow$ in the plane. Such graphs can be recognized effectively ([Felsner](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~felsner/Paper/gigdim.pdf) et al.). A 3DORG is the intersection graph of a finite family of rays directed $\leftarrow$ or $\to$or $\uparrow$ in the plane. For example, $C_6$ is a 3DORG but not 2DORG. Can 3DORG be recognized efficiently?

> **Problem** (Chaplick, Kindermann, Lipp, Wolff): 
>   Is the recognition of 3DORG in the class $\mathcal P$.

Here $\mathcal P$ is the class of problems of polynomial complexity.

(The problem was written 8.11.2015 by Alexander Wolff on [page 19](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=0&page=19) of [Volume 0](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=0) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/)).

The prize for solution: *Lunch in Würzburg*.

Comment: If somebody can edit to provide a more useful title (i.e., a title conveying some information to somebody who has no idea what a 3DORG is), it would be a useful contribution. As the description of the question is not clear enough for me to understand it, I'm unable to rewrite the title by myself.

Comment: @YCor I have reformulated the title. Now is it more understandable?

Comment: The title is OK now (I edited to fix English). But my lack of understanding is unrelated to the title. I understand what is the intersection graph of a family of sets, and I don't see how to make things make sense (what exactly is a ray and how to define an intersection graph for these).

Comment: a better reference is a paper http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~felsner/Paper/gigdim.pdf

Comment: @YCor: A ray is defined as usual. What you might be missing is that because a ray is infinite in one direction, that limits the kind of intersections it may have compared to segments.

Comment: OK, I eventually understood the problem (except precisely what kind of algorithm is desired, see my next comment), with the help of the picture in the "book". Took me some more time to decipher (e.g., that "They" in the second sentence refers to 2DORG, among graphs). Of course this is obvious once one has understood the problem, but when to start with, one is not familiar with "intersection graph", it takes some steps to converge to an understanding.

Comment: On the question again, you use the words "effectively" and "efficiently". I'm not aware of a difference between these two words, and I'm not aware of a mathematical meaning for any of them. Also the title asks whether some problem has polynomial complexity, and the question does not refer to polynomial complexity. What is to be understood? For context, to start with, is there an algorithm at all? one can obviously enumerate all 3DORGS, and I can't say more.